# Tool/script to find and modify numerical values in CSS file?

Tags: css, batch-file, operations

I simply want to go through and find every numerical value in a single, or batch of, CSS files and multiple times two, then save.

Any suggestions for the easiest way to do this?

Comment: Be prepared for a lot of unexpected results.

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: I don't have a solution to your problem, but to avoid these issues in the future, you can look at using extended stylesheet langues like SASS or LESS.

Comment: That's a really bizarre question. I guess you can just read a token, check if it's a number and multiply it by two, and write to a file.

Comment: find all numeric value?
you mean the numbers?

Comment: Deceptively simple question, no simple answer. For each line in every file you grab, you'll have to parse characters until you get to a number, then read it and all consecutive digits into a variable until you get to a non-digit, then multiply that whole number (assuming there's no decimal) by 2, replace the number with the doubled value. With that done, you'll then have to repeat the search until done. How to code this I don't know, but that's the process. Good luck.

Answer (score 1):

Using regular expressions could solve your problem.  For example, in python you could do the following:

```
import re

input = "#content {width:100px;height:20.5%;font-size:150.25%;margin-left:-20px;padding:2 0 -20 14.33333;}"

regex = re.compile("-?[.0-9]+")
scaled_numbers = [float(n)*2 for n in re.findall(regex, input)]
split_text = re.split(regex, input)

output = ''
for i in range(len(scaled_numbers)):
    output += "%s%.2f" % (split_text[i], scaled_numbers[i])

output += split_text[-1]
```

This code could be reduced in length, but I've deliberately left it less compact for readability.  One flaw with it is that it contracts floats to only 2 decimal places, but that can be easily changed if you really need extended decimals (change the number in `"%s%.2f"` to the desired number of places).

Note also that this code could change the names of CSS selectors (for example, `#footer-2` would become `#footer-4.00`).  If you wanted to avoid that, you'll need to adjust the code to ignore text outside of `{...}`.